# split data by falling edge in values for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a data set that in a given column A the values have the following pattern.

```
A B C D E
0 - - - - 
0 - - - - 
0 - - - - 
20 - - - - 
20 - - - - 
20 - - - - 
20 - - - - 
20 - - - - 
0 - - - - 
0 - - - - 
0  - - - - 
10 - - - - 
10 - - - -
```

and i would like to group each event to show the following

```
A B C D E
0 - - - - 
0 - - - - 
0 - - - - 
20 - - - - 
20 - - - - 
20 - - - - 
20 - - - - 
20 - - - -

0 - - - - 
0 - - - - 
0  - - - - 
10 - - - - 
10 - - - -
```

basically i am looking to split the dataframe by a falling edge in the data stream on column A.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute groups starting whenever there is a decrease in value (i.e. when the `diff` is negative), then split using `groupby`:

```
dfs = [g for _,g in df.groupby(df['A'].diff().lt(0).cumsum())]
```

output:

```
dfs[0]

    A  B  C  D  E
0   0  -  -  -  -
1   0  -  -  -  -
2   0  -  -  -  -
3  20  -  -  -  -
4  20  -  -  -  -
5  20  -  -  -  -
6  20  -  -  -  -
7  20  -  -  -  -

dfs[1]

     A  B  C  D  E
8    0  -  -  -  -
9    0  -  -  -  -
10   0  -  -  -  -
11  10  -  -  -  -
12  10  -  -  -  -
```